# multipart/form-data message for file?

Tags: vb.net, multipartform-data

Trying to send a multi part message.  Below is the code is what I am using.  Then notice what is received at the server.  The first is sent from Python code and works the second is from the VB code.  What do I need to do to the payload to get the VB code to send the same data as what Python sent?

```
        Dim Myurl As String = "http://" & "192.168.33.136/job"
        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim FormData = New MultipartFormDataContent()
        Dim payloadData = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        payloadData.Add("key", FabMoKey)
        payloadData.Add("index", "0")
        payloadData.Add("file", "filename=" & Chr(34) & "Fred.sbp" & Chr(34) & "\r\nContent-Type:Text/plain  mx,10 \n mx,0 \r\n")

        For Each payloadItem In payloadData
            FormData.Add(New StringContent(payloadItem.Value), payloadItem.Key)
        Next


        Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Myurl)
        request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
        request.Content = FormData
        Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
```

What is receive at server

A message that works.  This was sent from a Python code example

```
    Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundarya0nvAqIq8dCKaGRy\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/plain)
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"\r\n
        Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n
        Line-based text data: text/plain (2 lines)
            MX, 10\n
            MX, 0
    Last boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundarya0nvAqIq8dCKaGRy--\r\n
```

Does not work.  This was sent from the above VB code.

```
    Boundary: \r\n--0e39c991-6b94-41f2-9cd0-933a79a3886b\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/plain)
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file\r\n\r\n
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n
        Line-based text data: text/plain (1 lines)
            filename="Fred.txt"\r\n Content-Type: Text/plain \r\n\r\n mx,10 \n mx,0 \r\n
    Last boundary: \r\n--0e39c991-6b94-41f2-9cd0-933a79a3886b--\r\n
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the ContentDisposition as in below

```
FormData(2).Headers.ContentDisposition = New System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") With {.Name = "file", .FileName = "Fred.sbp"}
```

The below now works

```
        Dim Myurl As String = "http://" & "192.168.1.141/job"
        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim FormData = New MultipartFormDataContent()
        Dim payloadData = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        payloadData.Add("key", FabMoKey)
        payloadData.Add("index", "0")
        For Each payloadItem In payloadData
            FormData.Add(New StringContent(payloadItem.Value), payloadItem.Key)
        Next

        FormData.Add(New StringContent("Mx,0"), "file")
        FormData(2).Headers.ContentDisposition = New System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") With {.Name = "file", .FileName = "Fred.sbp"}


        Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Myurl)
        request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
        request.Content = FormData
        Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
```